# Error when downloading jpg using python result in: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, url, jpeg, imagedownload

I've been trying to make a script that scrape 9gag and retreive posts from specific categories. 
The problem is when im trying to download the jpg pictures a certificate issue emerges.

Is there another way to download the pictures?

The url for each pictures can be presented somewhat like this:

https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aAgRxj0_460s.jpg
https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aDgAx0N_460s.jpg

The code for downloading the images:

```
def download(pictures, file_name, name):
    for images in pictures['url_images']:
        full_path = file_name + name + '.jpg'
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(images, full_path)
```

The following result is presented:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)>
```

Comment: could you verify link? print one of pictures['url_images'] end manually get acces by webbrowser. Maybe just one link is broken? Print out each link in loop to check it.

Comment: Are you using a work or school computer? They usually get ssl errors

Comment: it seems error in C/C++ library `ssl` or `OpenSSL`. Maybe it needs to be updated. It may use old certifications.

Comment: each link is solid and brings me to correct picture when i click the link @kacper

Comment: neither, currently using a macbook if that has something to do with the problem?@AlexHawking

Comment: I tried to update something called certifi without any sucess. Currently using Macbook Pro with Mojave 10.14.5 on it@furas

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your using python3 and urllib3 maybe try this:

```
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Not sure if this will help but fixed ssl errors I was getting when urllib.

Comment: I am! does this require any changing in the urllib code or do i put it in my script? (quite new in programing)

Comment: Just put it in your document towards the top